# Validation rules required_if with other condition (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.4, validationrules

I got a problem with validation rules with nested conditions.

```
class StoreRequest extends Request
{
        public function authorize(){
        return true;
        }

        public function rules(){
                return [
                    'type_id'     => 'required|integer',
                    'external_id' => 'required_if:type_id,==,3|integer',
                ];
        }
}
```

Indeed I want to :
- check the external_id only if the type_id equal to 3 
- and check if it's an integer.

When I post my form, the rules works when I select a type_id equal to 3.
But if I select another type_id, like 1 or 2, the validation does not pass :

> The external_id must be an integer.

I try to add the nullable condition but required_if does not work anymore

Did you have any idea ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your rule performs two checks that are independent of one another; just because the `external_id` field is not required when the `type_id` != 3, does not mean the integer check is ignored.

What you are looking for is a [conditional rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules), which gives you finer control of when to perform a check, e.g. :

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'type_id'   => 'required|integer'
]);

$validator->sometimes('external_id', 'required|integer', function($input) {
    return $input->type_id == 3;
});
```

When using form validation, you can access the underlying validator instance by overriding the `getValidatorInstance()` method:

```
class StoreRequest extends Request
{
        public function authorize(){
        return true;
        }

        public function rules(){
                return [
                    'type_id'     => 'required|integer'
                ];
        }

        protected function getValidatorInstance() {
            $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();
            $validator->sometimes('external_id', 'required|integer', function($input) {
                return $input->type_id == 3;
            });
            return $validator;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Just came across the same problem and found the following answer that seems to work for me:

[issue-using-required-if-validation-rule-in-form-builder](https://pyrocms.com/fr/forum/channels/laravel/issue-using-required-if-validation-rule-in-form-builder)

```
     return [
                'type_id'     => 'required|integer',
                'external_id' => 'required_if:type_id,==,3|nullable|integer',
            ];
```

**Result for me:**

field not populated, type id not 3 - pass

field not populated, type id 3 - fail - required field

field populated, type id 3, non-integer - fail in integer rule

field populated, type id 3, integer - pass - all good!

note - think nullable rule came in Laravel 5.3

Comment: The link that you provided is broken.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @Nick A i know it works if the operation is `=` but i tried to use the `>` operator and it always says: `required if value is 2`. I tried: `required_if:value, >, 2`  
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

try this
pass the value directly
refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/validatorjs

**"required_if:anotherfield,value"**

The field under validation must be present and not empty if the another field field is equal to any value.

```
'type_id'     => 'required|integer',
'external_id' => 'required_if:type_i,3|integer',
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the easy way is

```
'type_id'     => 'required|integer',
'external_id' => $this->type_id === 3 ? 'required|integer' : 'nullable',
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
  class StoreRequest extends Request
    {
            public function authorize(){
            return true;
            }

            public function rules(){
                    return [
                        'type_id'     => 'required|integer',
                        'external_id' => 'required_if:type_id|in:3|integer',
                    ];
            }
    }
```