# How to conditionally validate request fields in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

My variable `carType` gets a string value.

If `additionalFields` variable is `carType` should be required when it is a *truck* or *caravan*.

If `carType` is a *truck*, then `additionalFields` should be array.

```
'carType' => 'string',
'additionalFields' => 'required_if:carType,truck,caravan',
```

How do I add an array validation based on condition?

Comment: https://www.manifest.uk.com/blog/laravel-conditional-validation-rules

Comment: You can accept both 'array|object' as validation rule and then check in your logic whether the given data is an array or object. If you want to do this in your validation, then you can check the value of `$this->get('carType')` if it's a caravan or truck and array_merge the rules in your other rules.

Comment: Hope that this is what you want
https://stackoverflow.com/q/42320292/9892571