Laravel 9 greater or equal but only if other field exists or is not null
I would like to use gte validation for some numbers but it seems the rule works only if both fields exists in POST request.
The rules looks like:
'min_points' => 'nullable|integer|min:0',
'max_points' => 'nullable|integer|min:0|gte:min_points',

As I said when I send POST request without min_points I get an error: The max points must be greater than or equal min points.
Do I need to set up custom validation for max_points which will check if min_points exists and is not null?

When you have rule dependencies between fields that are optional you'll have to write some custom logic. There are answers to similar  questions which might help you out, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320989/243925
